# String type not allowed at config change android manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I've been trying all the solutions I could find but I'm still facing the problem

```
Error APT0000: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'density|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|touchscreen|uiMode'). (APT0000)
```

I've tried switching the target API but it still did not work, my current minSdkVersion is 10 and targetSdkVersion is 23.

EDIT: Added the part which caused the error in Manifest

```
<activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:configChanges="density|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Test" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.Testing.Test.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2nd EDIT: I'm using Xamarin.Android so this is what I did at the Main Activity

```
Activity(
    Label = "Test",
    Name = "com.Testing.Test.MainActivity",
    MainLauncher = true,
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
    ConfigurationChanges =ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden|ConfigChanges.Keyboard|ConfigChanges.LayoutDirection|ConfigChanges.ScreenSize|ConfigChanges.Orientation|ConfigChanges.Density|ConfigChanges.FontScale|ConfigChanges.Locale|ConfigChanges.Mcc|ConfigChanges.Mnc|ConfigChanges.Navigation|ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout|ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize|ConfigChanges.Touchscreen|ConfigChanges.UiMode
)]
```

3rd Edit: I've realized that Android Manifest is automatically generated by Xamarin.Android. So every solution I've tried was editing the Manifest, which would be replaced by the Manifest generated by Xamarin.

Comment: paste you manifest file.

Comment: Whats your `[Activity()]` code in your main activity.?

Comment: Try removing that name attribute and please only put necessary config changes if it is just portrait why you need all these config changes?

Comment: Removing the name attribute didn't fix it.

Comment: I know this is late, but I believe it's the `density` attribute as it has no counterpart in the Android documentation that I've seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: You should also try one of the builds in the beta/alpha channel as it might contain a fix for the problem as this should work out of the box.

Comment: Finally, ensure you have updated your Android SDK tooling completely!

Answer (score 0):

> Error APT0000: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
>   'density|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|touchscreen|uiMode').
>   (APT0000)

your upper Error is come from here in your `Manifest.xml`.

```
android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|touchscreen|uiMode"
```

`screenSize` attributes are not available in `SDK 10`.They are been introduced in `API level 13`

see this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

So Change your SDK  `minSdkVersion  10` to   `minSdkVersion  13` the error is no more there.

Comment: @Mr Anoimus did you try my solution.

Comment: what build file are you talking about?

Comment: @MrAnoimus where you define `minSdkVersion  10` code ??

Comment: The manifest, seems to be automatically generated by Xamarin. I tried changing the minSdkVersion on the properties it changes the MinSdKVersion in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting this in the manifest if it is Xamarin.Android instead use something similar to this on your activity

```
[Activity(Label = "ScreenoffLogin",  Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",LaunchMode=Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class ScreenoffLogin : MvxActivity
    {
```

Comment: I didn't set this at the manifest, it auto generates the configchanges. Even if I try removing it, it will generate it back.

Comment: You haven't set anything similar to what has been shown above too??

Comment: I did, but I'm not sure why its having error at the manifest file

Comment: these attributes are added to manifest at compile time that's why its giving error in manifest, try removing all except the label attribute and then clean and build

Comment: I've removed it and another error(probably not related to this question) popped up.

Comment: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil;